# "Cannot read property 'length' of null" with Angular-cli and a json file

Tags: json, d3.js, angular-cli, crossfilter

I've got a mistake when I want to load data in a json file in my angular-cli project

When I use a .csv file like this it's working properly :

Main.ts

```
const data = require('file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./data/data.csv');
```

AppComponent.ts

```
constructor(private service: Service) {
    let psv = d3.dsv(";", "text/plain");
    let __self = this;
    psv("data.csv", function (data) {
        __self.service.emit({
            "data": data,
            "filter": crossfilter(data)
        });
    });
}
```

But when I want to use a .json file, with the next code :

Main.ts

```
const data = require('file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./data/data.json');
```

AppComponent.ts

```
    constructor(private service: Service) {
    let __self = this;
    let psv = d3.json("data.json", function (data) {
        __self.service.emit({
            "data": data,
            "filter": crossfilter(data)
        });
    });
}
```

I got the following error in my web-browser :

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

If someone have an idea, I'll be glad to know it!

[EDIT]

I follow the Gordon instructions, and I have made a `console.log(error)` and it returns

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.d3_json (eval at module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:9540:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.respond (eval at module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1944:29)
at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onload] (zone.js:1190)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:363)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:362)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:416)`
```

And in the browser console, in the Source tab, by clicking on the data.json, I have this :

`module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "data_mares.json";`

Comment: Like `d3.csv` and `d3.psv`, `d3.json` passes the error to the callback first (the signature is `callback(error, data)`) - so I'm surprised if the old code worked. Generally speaking, the way to debug this kind of problem is to add `console.log(data)` to your callback, and look in the browser console.

Comment: When I add `console.log(data)` in my callback function in AppComponent.ts, It displays `null`, so the .json file is not imported properly, I do not understand why

Comment: Read the first part of my comment. The first argument is the error not the data. You need two parameters in your callback.

Comment: @Gordon That information is not fully correct. Providing just one parameter is perfectly fine, in which case it will always be the data. Any information about an error will be lost, though. For an explanation have a look at my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/altocumulus/02t4yb27/). `data` being null indicates an error while loading, where the `error` parameter would admittedly come handy. The real question is why the loading fails, which cannot be answered with the information provided thus far.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that, thanks! That's kind of a dangerous design of d3, actually. It's never a good idea to ignore errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help Gordon

I follow your instructions, and I have made a `console.log(error)` and it returns

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.d3_json (eval at module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:9540:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.respond (eval at module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1944:29)
at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onload] (zone.js:1190)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:363)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:362)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:416)`
```

And in the browser console, in the Source tab, by clicking on the data.json, I have this :

`module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "data_mares.json";`

Comment: As this is not an answer but additional information to the question, please edit this into your original post.

Comment: On the other hand it is not that far from being an answer, since it clearly shows the reason, why the loading/parsing fails: your file does not contain valid JSON!

Comment: But when I use `import 'data.json'` at the top of the AppComponent.ts file in the Source tab in the browser, by clicking on the data.json file, I have 'module.exports = [{....' and the content of my json file appears properly